# Use company name(Account) and not Contact as Lead

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

An Lead in Dynamics CRM is always a person(Contact). Is it possible to change it such that a Lead points to an organization(Account)? In the business scenario that I am working on, the lead is supposed to be a company and not a person. The rest of the qualification process is fine. 
If the above is not possible, can I create a custom entity that can be qualified into an opportunity? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

By default a Lead already has lookups to both Contact and Account.

You could change the LastName field on Lead from Business Required to Optional and remove the FirstName and LastName field from the form (and the Existing Contact-field from the BPF, depending on your version of CRM).

When qualifying the lead with the above changes in place, no contact will automatically be created. Your leads will thus in essence be changed to only relate to Accounts.

Comment: The first name, last name, the relationships to the account and contact cannot be deleted. Even if I am to populate the name field using a workflow CRM will create a contact using that name.

Comment: I am not talking about deleting any relationships. Are you saying it is not possible to change the Business Required level of LastName? Are you saying it is not possible to remove the fields from the form?
I just confirmed that the approach works in an online demo instance (it is not clear which version of CRM you are using, since you tagged with 2011, 2013, and 2015, so something might be different between versions).